# Attach connection to Glue job orchestrated by AWS Airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am trying to trigger a glue job by Airflow. Triggering works great but it is going to timeout because of the missing Redshift connection. When I add the connection manually inside Job details tab glue job works. Is there a way to attach a connection to Redshift that would appear in Job details tab in triggered Glue? If I add it manually it gets removed on next Airflow run.

I would like to avoid using psycopg2 or other libraries in Glue if possible.

```
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.glue import GlueJobOperator

project='<project>'
env='<env>'
region_name='<region>'
glue_script='<script_name>'
job_name='<name>'

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date' : datetime(2022, 11, 12)
}

# Creating DAG Object
dag = DAG(dag_id=f'{project}-c-p-dag-{env}',
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval='@once',
          catchup=False
          )

# The DummyOperator is a task and does nothing
start = EmptyOperator(
    task_id='start', dag=dag
)

submit_glue_job = GlueJobOperator(
    task_id="submit_glue_job",
    job_name=f"{project}-{job_name}-{env}-{region_name}",
    iam_role_name="<role>",
    s3_bucket=f"s3://{project}-g-a-{env}-{region_name}",
    script_location=f"s3://{project}-g-a-{env}-{region_name}/scripts/{glue_script}",
    create_job_kwargs={"GlueVersion": "3.0", "NumberOfWorkers": 2, "WorkerType": "G.1X"},
    region_name=region_name,
    script_args={'--AWS_REGION': region_name,
    '--REDSHIFT_SECRET': '<secret>',
    '--REDSHIFT_DATABASE': '<db>',
    '--RS_DB_TABLE': '<table>',
    '--DYNAMODB_TABLE': '<dynamotable>'},
    dag=dag
)

start >> submit_glue_job
```

Answer (score 2):

Added Connections under create_job_kwargs and worked!

```
submit_glue_job = GlueJobOperator(
task_id="submit_glue_job",
job_name=f"{project}-{job_name}-{env}-{region_name}",
iam_role_name="<role>",
s3_bucket=f"s3://{project}-g-a-{env}-{region_name}",
script_location=f"s3://{project}-g-a-{env}-{region_name}/scripts/{glue_script}",
create_job_kwargs={"GlueVersion": "3.0", "NumberOfWorkers": 2, "WorkerType": "G.1X", "Connections":{"Connections":["<glue_connection_name>"]}, },
region_name=region_name,
script_args={'--AWS_REGION': region_name,
'--REDSHIFT_SECRET': '<secret>',
'--REDSHIFT_DATABASE': '<db>',
'--RS_DB_TABLE': '<table>',
'--DYNAMODB_TABLE': '<dynamotable>'},
dag=dag
```

)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. Also, since you are answering your own question, make sure that your question and ansewr are clear enough for others that run into a similar problem. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).